# How I can print just location from headers Curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have this script when I open it I get CURLOPT_HEADER but I went to print just location

```
<?php
    //Set the URL value
        $url = "http://example.com/ch1";

        //Initialize the cURL session
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'R-Auth: e3MVCXtgCXtnD3ITN3NhcyIzfXRhN3Jncntgf3tlc3s=';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        //Include header information in a file
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

        //Execute the cURL session
        curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

When I open the script I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 OK 
Server: nginx 
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 12:45:18 GMT 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Connection: close 
Location: http://example.com/ch2 
Referrer-Policy: origin
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php; turn off `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, then check `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL`. Probably check the status code, too, in case it doesn't always send a 301/302.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks , but i need to print just location can you help me with this